# 3-torsion part of Brauer group

Tags: brauer-groups, division-algebras

I want to solve this problem:

If in field $K$ we have sufficient n-th roots of unity then the 3-torsion part of Brauer group is generated by classes of cyclic algebras

I know that every element in 3-torsion part of Brauer group can we  written as a class of power normed residue algebra but how can we write it as cyclic algebra?

Comment: That follows from the Merkurjev-Suslin theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: Merkurjev-Suslin says that some map is isomorphism.Do you mean that?

Comment: The Merkurjev-Suslin theorem states that the norm residue homomorphism is surjective.  Thus, assuming that there is a primitive $3^{\text{rd}}$ root of unity in $K$ to trivialize $\mu_3$, every element of $H^2(K;\mu_3) \cong H^2(K;\mu_3^{\otimes 2})$ is a sum of images of primitive symbols in Milnor K-theory.  Each of these primitive symbols maps to the Brauer class of a cyclic algebra.  Thus, every Brauer class is a sum of classes of cyclic algebras (but there are very few results on the *symbol length*, i.e., the least number of such classes necessary to represent a given Brauer class).

Comment: But sorry.I understand that  these primitive roots of unity maps to power norm residue algebra but why these are cyclic algebra?

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote.  Primitive roots of unity do not map to anything.  The primitive symbols that generate Milnor K-theory map to Brauer classes of symbol algebras.  Symbol algebras are cyclic algebras.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I am properly understanding the question, but a result of Merkurjev, published shortly after the Merkurjev-Suslin theorem, shows (among other things) that the 3-torsion part of the Brauer group is generated by cyclic algebras:

Merkurjev, A. S., "Brauer groups of fields," Comm. Algebra 11 (1983), no. 22, 2611–2624.

I don't have the paper in front of me, but I believe the argument is via descent: first using the fact that the statement is true after adjoining a primitive (3rd in this case) root of unity, and then showing the cyclic algebras can be made to descent to be defined over the ground field.